# "one does not parade the fact that one is All-Knowing" meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> But **one does not parade the fact that one is All-Knowing**. I frequently act as though I am not possessed of the Inner Eye, so as not to make others nervous.

I'm not sure if I have gotten the meaning right. As I understand, it means: *one does not show off the fact: he knows all the things.* Is my understanding correct?

Another thing I'm not sure is if the first 'one' and the second 'one' refer to the same person. If so, shouldn't we use 'he' to refer back to the first 'one'? *But one does not parade the fact that he is All-Knowing.*

What does the sentence convey exactly?

Comment: In the game of poker, one does not parade the fact that one has a straight flush.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Maybe, they do with a full-house? :)

Comment: Only if they want to win a small pot.

Comment: There is no need for all-knowing and inner eye to be in caps unless you mean: God. Is this poker or daily life? That use of caps, though used by the current US "president", sounds like German usage. I believe that German capitalizes certain nouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: "parade" in this context means "show off".

You are also right that this sentence would be clearer if the second "one" was replaced by "he" or "she",  but even better would be:

"one does not parade the fact that they are All-Knowing"

because this does not involve any assumptions about gender (he or she).

Comment: No, one is correct in both instances in the first sentence. You don't change pronouns in mid-stream (in the middle of a sentence using the pronoun one.) One does not parade the fact one is all-knowing. There is no need to change the pronoun at all.

Comment: @Lambie: It might be a bit "odd" to switch from ***one*** to ***she***, but it's perfectly natural to switch to ***he*** or ***they*** - as will be the case with many/most written instances of [*If one knows that he (is all-knowing, or whatever).*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if+one+knows+that+he%22) I think many people would prefer to do this, if only because one ***one*** isn't necessarily "pretentious", but the more it's repeated, the more it becomes so.

Comment: They makes it even more ambiguous. One=a person,they=plural people who are all knowing. No one would default to the gender assumption here. And if they did, it would be just as bad.

Answer (score 1):

**Original sentence and stylistic considerations in formal writing.**

1) But **one does not parade the fact that one is all-knowing**. I frequently act as though I am not possessed of the Inner Eye, so as not to make others nervous.

This is formal writing. Use of **one** triggers that interpretation. Ergo, there is no reason to switch pronouns beside the issue of ambiguity. Please read on.

2) But **one does not parade the fact that he (or she) is all-knowing**. I frequently act as though I am not possessed of the Inner Eye, so as not to make others nervous.

As the second sentence has I/I, it is stylistically better to keep one/one in the first sentence. Also, **if you switch the second one to he or she**, it could refer to some else,thereby introducing ambiguity. What I mean is this: the **he** could refer to a person other than the person referred to as one, the subject pronoun.

It is conceivable to read 2), therefore, as: 
But **one [referring to oneself or someone else] does not parade the fact that he [John]  is all-knowing**. I frequently act as though I am not possessed of the Inner Eye, so as not to make others nervous.

The best way to contrast the two sentences is: one/one and I/I.

"One should be careful of her manners in the forums." Hmm, that makes my point.

I left inner eye in caps to emphasize it.